# How to format date-time diff in excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns with dates in a numeric format (1231.231). I create a third column with their difference (e.g., 4.061805555). How can I format this to show "4 1:29"? I don't want to create string values in the column, just format how the data is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the cell.

Choose "Format Cells".

Choose "Custom" from the Category dropdown on the Number tab.

Type `d h:mm` as your chosen format.

Comment: d h:mm will present the day as day of month in the calendar. 4.06 is converted to 5 1:29, which is incorrect.

Comment: In my Excel, 4.06 gets formatted to 4 1:26, as expected. Are you sure you're typing the format correctly? What is your Excel version? What is your locale?

Comment: @IttayD It is returning the correct value on my end as well. Maybe it really has something to do with your local.